# How to add a page that print "Hello World" to an existing asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I downloaded an ASP.NET project to my local computer via FTP and opened it in Visual Studio.

Currently the folder structure looks like following:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to add a new page which i can visit through domain.com/hello and prints "hello world" ?

I could not figure it out myself as I can't see any Controllers or Models folder. I also couldn't find how urls are being routed. When i visit domain.com/about I see the about page of the site which has its code in the following path:  Views\Home\About.cshtml

But i'm not sure who is telling the site that /about should be routed to that file. I couldn't find any routes file.

Comment: This looks like a compiled version of the website, go grab the original source code and what you're seeking should be in there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So basically, I want to add a page which serves RSS data to this existing website. So would this be impossible to do in case where we dont have access to source ? ( because the site's owner bought it from someone else and he might not have the uncompiled version of source code )

Comment: Then you will have to decompile it and hope you can get it working. However, if you bought this as a final product there may be licensing issues with what you want to accomplish. My best advice would be to go back to the original author and ask them to add what you want.

Answer (score -1):

1. You should create folder Controllers
2. Create Controller in folder with name CustomController
3. Create Action in controller Hello() which the return ur View "return View()"
4. Create folder in ur Views -> Custom
5. add Hello.cshtml in folder
6. go to App_Data
7. find your Routing File
8. And Add new Route for ur app
9. `routes.MapRoute(
       name: "hello",
       url: "hello",
       defaults: new
       {
           controller = "Custom",
           action = "Hello"
       }
   );`

   Done